# Expand a pandas column without merge

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
    A   B   C
0   2  19  12
1   5  17  13
2   6  16  19
3   7  11  16
4  10   1  11
```

And I want it to expand on column A like this:

```
    A     B     C
0   2  19.0  12.0
1   3   NaN   NaN
2   4   NaN   NaN
3   5  17.0  13.0
4   6  16.0  19.0
5   7  11.0  16.0
6   8   NaN   NaN
7   9   NaN   NaN
8  10   1.0  11.0
```

This is how I do it currently, creating a numpy array that contains list of dense integers, and then `merge` it with the DataFrame, this create the dataframe shown above:

```
new_arr = np.arange(df.iloc[0,0], df.iloc[-1,0]+1)
new_col = pd.Series(new_arr).to_frame()
new_col.columns = ['A']
new_df = pd.merge(new_col, df, on='A', how='left')
```

But I feels like there must be a better way to directly use a series to expand the dataframe without using `merge`, or even a pandas native function on the original dataframe? Thanks ahead for any solution.

Here's the first df for easier replication:

```
pd.DataFrame([[2, 19, 12], [5, 17, 13], [6, 16, 19], [7, 11, 16], [10, 1, 11]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `reindex` after setting `A` as the index:

```
>>> df.set_index('A').reindex(range(df.A.min(),df.A.max()+1)).reset_index()
    A     B     C
0   2  19.0  12.0
1   3   NaN   NaN
2   4   NaN   NaN
3   5  17.0  13.0
4   6  16.0  19.0
5   7  11.0  16.0
6   8   NaN   NaN
7   9   NaN   NaN
8  10   1.0  11.0
```

Note, you can also use the `np.arange` and `iloc` that you have in your question instead of `range`:

```
df.set_index('A').reindex(np.arange(df.iloc[0,0], df.iloc[-1,0]+1)).reset_index()
```

Comment: Awesome. Knew there was a better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An option using generators

```
def f(df):
  a = df.A.min()
  n, m = df.shape
  nans = tuple(np.nan for _ in range(m - 1))

  for t in zip(*map(df.get, df)):
    while a < t[0]:
      yield (a,) + nans
      a += 1
    yield t
    a += 1

pd.DataFrame([*f(df)], columns=df.columns)

    A     B     C
0   2  19.0  12.0
1   3   NaN   NaN
2   4   NaN   NaN
3   5  17.0  13.0
4   6  16.0  19.0
5   7  11.0  16.0
6   8   NaN   NaN
7   9   NaN   NaN
8  10   1.0  11.0
```